# How can I decode a string from base64 to binary to decrypt it with RSA in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, binary, base64

I have an encrypted string with RSA that I have encoded in base64 to put it in a QR-code:

```
echo "thesearesecretlogininfos"|openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem |openssl base64
```

Then I scan the Qr Code and get the base64 encoded (and RSA encrypted) string to a flutter app. Now I'm trying to decrypt it using the [encrypt package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) and I just can't get it to work. It just won't take my encrypted base64 string and don't get it decoded back to binary to decrypt it with RSA.

Here is the code of what I've tried:

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt_io.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/asymmetric/api.dart';

(...)
  String base64encryptedLoginID;
  String newloginID;

 void decrypt(BuildContext context) async {

       final myPrivateKey = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/private.pem');
       final myPublicKey = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/public.pem');
       final privateKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(myPrivateKey) as RSAPrivateKey;
       final publicKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(myPublicKey) as RSAPublicKey;

       final encrypter = Encrypter(RSA(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privateKey));
   
    final newloginID = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(base64encryptedLoginID));
```

I get the Error `ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Unsupported block type for private key: 153)` in the last line of code.

I also tried `final encryptedLoginID = utf8.decode(base64.decode(base64encryptedLoginID));` which gave me the error `FormatException (FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0x70 (at offset 2))`

Could anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: Could you clarify the issue with your current implementation.

Comment: Yes, it would be more helpful if you included the code of what you've done

Comment: I thought it was understandable like that - I've added the code in flutter now.

Comment: Which line in your code causes the issue? Is it `utf8.decode(base64.decode(base64encryptedLoginID)) ` or something else? It would help if you could isolate the one causing issue in your code and provide more Logs aside from `FormatException (FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0x70 (at offset 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(encrypted_string), iv: iv);
```